# Transistor for Signal Attenuation

Tags: transistors, audio, signal

I've been considering a circuit that could be used as an equalizer for an audio signal.  Specifically, I'm planning on using a set of filters (a cross-over) to split the input into respective channels, and then a set of transistors operating below saturation to act as variable resistors for each channel.  Right now this is just a rudimentary design I'm playing with.  Specifically: I know it's not the best design... it's just for play right now.

My question is this:
Is it reasonable to use transistors to attenuate a signal like this?  It'll be low power, but it seems like this will just be changing the impedance of each channel, which may have effects that I (being inexperienced in this area of electrical design) am not accounting for.

Any (constructive) feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, but transistors (FETs) are not particularly linear when used individually. This will give detectable distortion in your audio signal (unless you keep the amplitude v. low (mV), when noise will then dominate).

There are techniques using 2 FETs in parallel, and with a different VGS offset to make a variable resistor that is more linear over a non-zero range, but they do depend on FETs following the square-law characteristic which is not perfect. Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage-controlled_resistor will give you some starting points.

Comment: That link is extremely helpful.  Also, the non-linearity is something I hadn't even considered.  Thanks @jp314

Comment: You are probably better off to use a set of resistors as a DAC and FET switches to select the DAC tap point. You can use a an R-2R architecture, or just a string of resistors, and select a tap point digitally.